# solr delta-import "fetches" all data before "processing"?

Tags: mysql, solr

I use solr's DIH to delta import data from mysql to solr, but i found when the table has a large number of records (100000000), the delta-import need to fetch all the data before processing .
So it always cause a large memory consumption resulting in **Running Out of Memory**.
While when i do a full import operation, it may fetch a part of the data.

Is there any setting on the solr delta import to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to set the `batchSize` in your `data-config.xml`. Here's an example on how to do it:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-2" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mysqldatabase" batchSize="-1" user="root" password="root"/>
```

This example is taken from the following link: [DataImportHandler - Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#I.27m_using_DataImportHandler_with_a_MySQL_database._My_table_is_huge_and_DataImportHandler_is_going_out_of_memory._Why_does_DataImportHandler_bring_everything_to_memory.3F)

Another thing you might try is using the `full-import` command for your delta, but setting the `batchSize` has worked for me in the past. If you'd like to try using the `full-import` for your delta, visit the following link: [Full Import Delta - Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq#fullimportdelta)

Comment: while, it seems does't work and solr throws an exception that Fetch size must be a value greater to or equal to 0.By the way, I use postgresql for store my data.Using full-import instead of delta-import should be a possible approach, but i don't know it is a most suitable way to complete delta import data operation.Thank you for your answer.